# Programming tools for iPhone and iPod touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I heard that the programmings tools can be downloaded for free.

I also heard that the programmings tools cannot be downloaded for free.

Which is it?

Comment: You have **63 questions** with no accepted answers, you should consider accept answers on your questions, so users will be more enthusiastic to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Xcode/Interface Builder from http://developer.apple.com/mac/ if you don't feel like digging out your install disk. You can download the iPhone SDK from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/. After you download them, you can use them for free (and run your applications in the iPhone Simulator for free). You will need to sign up to be an Apple Developer for $100 USD if you want to submit your applications to the App Store or test them on any actual device.

Answer (score 7):

XCode and Interface Builder are free, optional installs that are included with OS X.  The iPhone SDK is a free download from http://developer.apple.com.

The only not-free part is that you have to be a paid member of the Apple Developer Program if you want to deploy an app via the App Store, or to deploy it to your own hardware to test.  But if you just want to code and test using the iPhone simulator, it's all free.

Comment: actually you need to be a paid member to even deploy the app to your own hardware.

Answer (score 2):

they can be downloaded for free at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). Not too hard to find that out, btw.